# How to call method from a different class for user input selection with multiple variables

Tags: java, string, methods, switch-statement

I am building a simple calculator that asks for user to select the function.

The menu displays like this and user can select 1-5 as a choice as well as A, S, M, and D for it's respected function:

1. Addition
2. Subtraction
3. Multiplication
4. Subtraction

The calculator will then ask the user to select 2 floats separated by a space and calculates it and so on. It will reject any input that is not the above.

Anyways. I got most of the calculator coded. However, right now, I only have it coded to allow the user to choose 1-5 rather than 1-5 as well as the letters. I do have a separate code written to allow the user to choose either 1-5 or A, S, M, D but I do not know how to call that method to input it in to the main code for the calculator. In what format should i write the call in order to use the second snippet of code instead of the first so the user can input not only 1-5 but 1-5 and A, S, M or D. Thank you

Below is the section where i need to call for AskCalcChoice1 but i am getting an error AskCalcChoice1 cannot be resolved:

```
    while ((inputOperation = myAskCalcChoice1.userInput()) != 5) //Need to call for the method below but how?{
        calculatorCommands.pickNewSymbol("\n");
        calculatorCommands.putDownSymbol();
```

Below is the switch method from askCalcChoice1. How can i call for this method into the main calculator code?

import java.util.Scanner;

public class askCalcChoiceSwitch {

```
Scanner readInput = new Scanner(System.in); 

public float showResults(int choice, float [] f){
    float result = 0.00f;
    char input = readInput.nextLine().charAt(0);



        switch (input)  {

        case '1': result = f[0]+f[1]; break; //if user input choice 1, function will break after this
        case 'A': result = f[0]+f[1]; break; //if user input choice A, function will break after this 
        case '2': result = f[0]-f[1]; break; //if user input choice 2, function will break after this 
        case 'S': result = f[0]-f[1]; break; //if user input choice S, function will break after this
        case '3': result = f[0]*f[1]; break; //if user input choice 3, function will break after this
        case 'M': result = f[0]*f[1]; break; //if user input choice M, function will break after this 
        case '4': result = f[0]/f[1]; break; //if user input choice 4, function will break after this 
        case 'D': result = f[0]/f[1]; break; //if user input choice D, function will break after this
        default: System.out.println("Calculator cannot comprehend" + choice); break;

        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider using a switch statement.

Edit: I added a CalOperation interface and concrete types to encapsulate the math operation and simplify the code.

```
private CalcOperation calcChoice () {
    while (true) {
        String input = readInput.nextLine();
            switch (input) {
            case "1": //intentional fall through
            case "A":
                return new AddOperation();
            case "2": //intentional fall through
            case "S":
                return new SubtractOperation();
            case "3":  //intentional fall through
            case "M": 
                return new MultiplyOperation();
            case "4":  //intentional fall through
            case "D":
                return new DivideOperation();
            default:
                System.out.println("You have entered an invalid choice. Try again.");
                break;
         }
    }
}  

public interface CalcOperation {
    public double calculate(double d1, double d2);
}

public class AddOperation implements CalcOperation {

    @Override
    public double calculate (double d1, double d2) {
        return d1 + d2;
    }
}

//create implementations for SubtractOperation, MultiplyOperation, and DivideOperation
```

Comment: Now it's coded like this but im getting an error that 'input' and'A' cannot be resolved as a variable:switch (input) {
   
   case 1: result = f[0]+f[1]; break; //if user input choice 1, function will break after this
   case A: result = f[0]+f[1]; break; //if user input choice A, function will break after this

Comment: would it be easier if i call it by string?

Comment: I'll update with a more complete example for calcChoice

Comment: if i were to use the string, how do i call for this method that is in another class to input this funtionality into my main class which is the calculator?